# Random CGPoint x value not working

Tags: iphone, cgpoint, arc4random

I have 22 images... 11 are (rightwall1, rightwall2, rightwall3, etc) the other 11 are (leftwall1, leftwall2, leftwall3, etc)

I am placing each one ontop of the other by setting their y value to the previous walls y value plus the height of the wall (all walls are the same height).

This works fine!

Now, I was trying to set the x value using arc4random so they would jump all over the place in a certain range ( For the left walls: (-35 to 15) & For the right walls: (330 to 405) )...

The right walls work perfectly, but the left walls, some of them work but most of them don't show up on the screen.

I manually set the x value of one to -45 and it showed up on the screen and that is lower than the arc4random allows it to go.

The only problem I can think of is i'm subtracting wrong for the left walls?

Here is the code to set the walls locations, I have no other code in the whole project yet.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

        rightWall1.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), (460-((rightWall1.frame.size.height)/2)) );//460 = bottom of screen
        rightWall2.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall1.center.y)-(rightWall2.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall3.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall2.center.y)-(rightWall3.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall4.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall3.center.y)-(rightWall4.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall5.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall4.center.y)-(rightWall5.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall6.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall5.center.y)-(rightWall6.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall7.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall6.center.y)-(rightWall7.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall8.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall7.center.y)-(rightWall8.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall9.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall8.center.y)-(rightWall9.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall10.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall9.center.y)-(rightWall10.frame.size.height)) );
        rightWall11.center = CGPointMake( ((arc4random()%75)+330), ((rightWall10.center.y)-(rightWall11.frame.size.height)) );


        leftWall1.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), (460-((leftWall1.frame.size.height)/2)) );
        leftWall2.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall1.center.y)-(leftWall2.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall3.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall2.center.y)-(leftWall3.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall4.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall3.center.y)-(leftWall4.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall5.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall4.center.y)-(leftWall5.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall6.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall5.center.y)-(leftWall6.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall7.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall6.center.y)-(leftWall7.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall8.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall7.center.y)-(leftWall8.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall9.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall8.center.y)-(leftWall9.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall10.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall9.center.y)-(leftWall10.frame.size.height)) );
        leftWall11.center = CGPointMake( (15-(arc4random()%50)), ((leftWall10.center.y)-(leftWall11.frame.size.height)) );

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be (arc4random()%50)-15?

Comment: Nope, I want a range of 15 to -35...
If I use this: (15-(arc4random()%50)) 
Shouldn't it return that? It does, but when I set an images xvalue to this: (15-(arc4random()%50)) some of the images are disappearing either off the screen or alltogether, I can't tell. 

This works: (15-(arc4random()%15)) But that gives me a range of 0-15
If I change it to something like this though: (15-(arc4random()%20)) Images start dissapearing, even if it was (15-20) that's only -5, If I manually set the images x value to -5 it still shows up, so does -65... ???

Comment: oh wait sorry, that wont do it. (((CGFloat) arc4random()/(CGFloat)0xFFFFFFFFu) * (35 - 15)) + 15

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, unfortunately, this did not work: (15+((-1)*(arc4random()%50)))

Comment: What is this: (CGFloat)0xFFFFFFFFu) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't get a negative integer value using arc4random (Makes sense because arc4random uses modulus.... integer... ?? haha) So I use a float...

can't say:

```
(-1)*(arc4random() ....
```

You have to say:

```
float num1;
num1 = -1;
(num1)*(arc4random() ....
```

Weird... Same goes for subtracting... you have to add a negative 1 float times the arc4random ..